# bibliography not compatible with author-year citations, with all authors and years included

Tags: bibtex, natbib, author-number

I cannot get my citations to work using `natbib`, compiling the entire document gives an error

> Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.

My preamble is the following:

```
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, right=1in, left=1.5in]{geometry}  % set the margins to 1in on all sides  
\usepackage{graphicx}              % to include figures  
\usepackage{amsmath}               % great math stuff  
\usepackage{amsfonts}              % for blackboard bold, etc  
\usepackage{amsthm}                % better theorem environments  
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage{natbib}
```

And at the bottom:

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}  
\bibliography{references}
```

When I run tex, everything comes out more or less as expected (meaning the references appear at the end), but with numbers where I use `\cite` rather than author-year.

All of my references have the authors and years, so that shouldn't be a problem.

The only idea I have is when I run the .bib on its own, I get lots of overfull `\hbox` warnings. For example,

> Overfull \hbox (7.13487pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 17--26
>   []\tenrm @articlearcidiacono2004ability, ti-tle=Ability sort-ing and the re-tur
>   ns to col-lege ma-jor, au-thor=Arcidiacono|

Which makes no sense to me, since this shouldn't be an issue. The lines it is referencing:

```
@article{arcidiacono2004ability,  
    title={Ability sorting and the returns to college major},  
    author={Arcidiacono Peter},  
    journal={Journal of Econometrics},  
    volume={121},  
    number={1},  
    pages={343--375},  
    year={2004}  
}
```

I have no longer URLS or anything like that, I have also tried using cleveref instead of natbib (which causes other problems), plain and AER bib styles, changing the indentation of everything in the references a few different ways, and everything outlined in the "similar questions" on this cite.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Compiling a document with the code you've provided doesn't lead to any error. Please add a [minimal (non) working example (M(N)WE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Welcome to the [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Yes, please, make it a working example, it is so time consuming to even start working on your problem. One single block of all your codes will do this job and it will help solvers tremendously.

Comment: Please indicate, at the very least, which document class you use, how the `natbib` package is loaded, and how the entry with key `arcidiacono2004ability` is cited. (The overfull line warning you get sure makes it sound like you're including the contents of the bib file directly, rather than via `\cite` commands and a call to BibTeX.)